# Why marks IntelliJ my Deprecated groovy constructor not as deprecated

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, deprecated

I have following example Code:

```
class Test{

  @Deprecated
  Test(String par){
    println(par)
  }

  Test(int par){
    println(par)
  }

  @Deprecated
  void myFunc(){
    println("Hello")
  }

}

Test test = new Test("Griasdi")
test.myFunc()

Test test2 = new Test(1)
```

I want the  Test(String par) constructor and the myFunc Method be be marked as deprecated, But IntelliJ only marks the Method as Deprecated but not the constructor, see here on the Picture:
[image]

Does anybody know why the constructor is not marked as deprecated? Is this a Groovy thing or an IntelliJ issue?

Comment: unfortunately the groovy plugin hasn't been updated in almost 13 years. You can see if there are other plugins for providing code inspections, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Please report an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: "unfortunately the groovy plugin hasn't been updated in almost 13 years." - You may be referencing https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1524-groovy, but it is not the case that the Groovy support has not been updated in IntellIJ in 13 years.  We have introduced many language features during that time which JetBrains have released support for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a Groovy thing or an IntelliJ issue?

It is an IntelliJ thing.  Groovy isn't creating and annotating the editor in the IDE.